# Ruby on Rails - Setting up Bootstrap 3 - bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Iam trying to get this working:[twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), but if i type `bundle install`, i get the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
[...]
Using sqlite3 1.3.9

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/_Festplatte_D/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        [...]
C:/_Festplatte_D/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/
ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V
8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

        from C:/_Festplatte_D/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/lib
v8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/_Festplatte_D/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ru
by/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/_Festplatte_D/RubyOnRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gem
s/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I also tried this solution [therubyracer_for_windows](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4398451), but it didnt work for me...

I am using win7, ruby1.9.3, rails4, ...

Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: Not sure if this will work as I haven't  had that error yet. Try removing Gemfile.lock (delete it) and do a `bundle install` again to attempt recreating Gemfile.lock. That has worked a few times in my case

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow as soon as possible. I hope it'll work :]

Comment: It didnt work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh well. BTW I had trouble installing Bootstrap the first time. Check this out: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/, it might be useful. You can choose to automatically include Bootstrap, among other options (Devise, RSpec), etc. when creating apps.

Comment: Thanks, but thats quite too much for my small app as a project for my university. I'll add a answer no the bottom for people, who want a "easier" solution. Thanks anyways :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It's sounds quite stupid, but I uninstalled all Ruby-Versions (there are some left from a older project) and also uninstalled all, which depent on Ruby (Ruby on Rails).

Then I decided to google which version is stable and compatible each other (Ruby and RoR).
After that I installed `ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]` and `Rails 4.0.4`.

Furthermore I set up my environment variables as the follows:
(caus the old-version-path was just listed)

- Path
- %RUBY_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

&

- RUBY_HOME
- C:\Ruby193\

Finally I found this easy & quick [Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFLVduzQ87w).

Now everything is working.
Thanks anyways to all the guys above :]

Answer (score 0):

The gem you added is for bootstrap 2.3.2 read on the github repo you provided:

```
Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 for Rails Asset Pipeline
```

For bootstrap 3 you can also use the sass gem from the same authors: 
just add

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

on your Gemfile

Comment: I should read it carefully. BUT there is a [link](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3), and its quite the same installation-way.
whatever...
I added `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to my Gemfile, but the error appears again after `bundle install`. 
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. If you use the **[bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)** gem, which is the officially supported Bootstrap gem, you'll get the newest Bootstrap v3.2 and you won't have problems installing it on Windows.

For an example app that shows how to integrate Bootstrap with Rails, see:

> **[Rails and Bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap/)**

Comment: How do I use bootstraps-sass ?
Should I "only" add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to my Gemfile, as AndreDurao said ?
I did, but `bundle install` quite didnt work as you can see in the topic. What am I doing wrong ?